# Compare Build Code to Current Code Powershell - TFS - Deploy (Automation)

Tags: powershell, deployment, tfs, build, automation

Currently I create software builds in **TFS**, when Developers give the go a head to create a new build to the Test Server.

This will then create the new build in a new folder. The code will now need to be compared against the current code.

The comparison software tool used to compare latest code against current software code.

A manual copy is made from **Windows Explorer** to a new folder that is the latest package.

This package is then deployed to live servers manually.

I would either use **powershell**, or if someone could recommend a good software or script that can do the compare and allows me to filer or exclude files that i do not want to be in the package would be great. End goal for this is automation.

Process below:

`TFS BUILD SERVER ---> CREATES A BUILD ---> BUILD DEPLOYED TO TEST SERVER ---> COMPARISON TOOL ---> MANUAL FILE COPY TO CREATE PACKAGE ---> PACKAGE MANUALLY DEPLOYED TO LIVE`

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask You need to be specific about your question and show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Explore [ROBOCOPY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)'s options, that's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @giulioviarr do you know any examples of robocopy which has a exclude file command and a command to find differences. not sure if it is "*.*"

Comment: Robocopy is analogous to rsync: the difference criteria are file system based (attributes, timestamps), exclusion is guided by /xf and /xd option that you may specify multiple times. See some examples https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx and http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html, but you can search for more.
In the end you have to understand and play with options until you are satisfied with the result.

Comment: thank you i will check this out, and i may post another new question up soon. once i understand the way TFS works when automating deployments to test then to live production. @giulioviarr